# ANTLR 4 SQLite Grammar giving empty Token Stream

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am using an ANTLR4 grammar to parse SQLite Queries. However, the lexer is returning an empty token stream, even though I am using a  simple select query.

This  yields the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: nextToken requires a non-null input stream.
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:138)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.fetch(BufferedTokenStream.java:186)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.sync(BufferedTokenStream.java:169)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.setup(BufferedTokenStream.java:271)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.lazyInit(BufferedTokenStream.java:266)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream.LT(CommonTokenStream.java:116)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.enterRecursionRule(Parser.java:677)
>       at antlr.antlr4.SQLIte.SQLiteParser.expr(SQLiteParser.java:5109)
>       at antlr.antlr4.SQLIte.SQLiteParser.expr(SQLiteParser.java:5100)
>       at antlr.antlr4.SQLIte.LexerParser.main(LexerParser.java:38)

This is the code for the main.java class:

```
import antlr.antlr4.SQLIte.*;
import antlr.antlr4.SQLIte.SQLiteParser.ExprContext;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.NotNull;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LexerParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // The list that will hold our function names.
        final List<String> functionNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        // The select-statement to be parsed.
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

        // Create a lexer and parser for the input.
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sql.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 0, 0);

        ANTLRInputStream antlrTemp = new ANTLRInputStream(stream);
        SQLiteLexer lexer = new SQLiteLexer(antlrTemp);
       // SQLiteLexer lexer = new SQLiteLexer(antlrTemp);
        CommonTokenStream cts = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        System.out.print(cts.getTokens());

        SQLiteParser parser = new SQLiteParser(cts);

            ExprContext theExpr = parser.expr();
            System.out.println("found expr " + theExpr.toString());
```

Where am I going wrong here?

[Grammar link](https://github.com/bkiers/sqlite-parser/tree/master/src/main/antlr4/nl/bigo/sqliteparser)

Comment: Why don't you use `new ANTLRInputStream(sql)` directly?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - That gives the same error. My token stream from the lexer is empty. Outputs [] when I use 
         CommonTokenStream cts = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        System.out.print(cts.getTokens());

Comment: Ok, I took a look at the grammar - you should use `parser.parse()` instead of `parser.expr()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just tried it though. The null token list problem persists.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - It works when I run it as a Maven project as opposed to a Java project :)

Comment: Ok, glad it works for you, but I'm not a Java guy so I have no clue what's the difference that makes it work... Maybe someone else could explain this.

Answer (score 0):

This code works if it is part of a Maven project. I earlier tried to run it as a Java project.

Thanks